# How to reduce excution time - email alert with installable onOpen trigger from a library

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this code in a library that is being called onOpen of multiple spreadsheets:

```
function emailAlerts() {
// sends email alert when accurate anchors is above treshold
  var linksSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('links');
  var Ssurl = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getUrl();
  var accuracyCellValue = linksSheet.getRange(3,4).getValue();
  var customerCellValue = linksSheet.getRange(1,5).getValue();
  var treshold = 15;
  if (accuracyCellValue > treshold) {
    var message = 'Attention! The accuracte anchors for the customer is ' + accuracyCellValue + '%, while the treshold is: ' + treshold + '%. Customer spreadsheet:' + Ssurl;
    var subject = 'Accurate anchors alert for customer ' + customerCellValue;
    MailApp.sendEmail('yaniv@mydomain.co.il','noreply@mydomain.co.il', subject, message);
  }
}
```

This works, but the problem is that it takes about 15 seconds for spreadsheets to finish loading when opened.

I really need to reduce the excution time to avoid users confusion.

I want to keep the function in a library for easy implementation of changes to all spreadsheets when needed.

I will be happy to hear any ideas.

Thanks!

P.S. there are a few onEdit triggers in the same library- all excuted very quickly.

Comment: I'm not sure you'll be able to speed this up significantly. I believe some of the delay is in gScripts queueing the request, etc. I don't know the context or purpose but could you get this code to run, say, every hour and not be dependent on someone opening the sheet?

Comment: I see what you mean, but unfortunately it is not possible for my context. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your code is slow is because it includes multiple calls to external servers, specifically to `SpreadsheetApp` and `MailApp`. Those calls are time-consuming. It is hard to significantly speed-up your code if those calls are necessary.

- You can speed up your code slightly by minimizing the amount of external calls - see [Apps Script Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#minimize_calls_to_other_services).

For example, modify:

```
var linksSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('links');
var Ssurl = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getUrl();
```

to

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var linksSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('links');
var Ssurl = spreadsheet.getUrl();
```

- Another optimization point is to move as much code as possible into the `if` statement, if there is no need to execute this code in case of the condition not being fulfilled.

Sample:

```
function emailAlerts() {
// sends email alert when accurate anchors is above treshold
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var linksSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('links');
  var accuracyCellValue = linksSheet.getRange(3,4).getValue();
  var treshold = 15;
  if (accuracyCellValue > treshold) {
    var customerCellValue = linksSheet.getRange(1,5).getValue();
    var Ssurl = spreadsheet.getUrl();
    var message = 'Attention! The accuracte anchors for the customer is ' + accuracyCellValue + '%, while the treshold is: ' + treshold + '%. Customer spreadsheet:' + Ssurl;
    var subject = 'Accurate anchors alert for customer ' + customerCellValue;
    MailApp.sendEmail('yaniv@mydomain.co.il','noreply@mydomain.co.il', subject, message);
  }
}
```

- Not directly applicable in your case, but in case you will need it in another situation: If you retrieve values from an adjacent range, it is significantly faster to retrieve the values of the whole range with `getValues()` rather than looping through cells and retrieve the value of each one individually with `getValues()`.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a faster way to call external servers? Or retrieve an active spreadsheet / send email in a different way?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think so. You can try out either `GmailApp` is faster than `MailApp`. Is your spreadsheet heavily loaded with data? This might slow your calls additionally down.Mind also that `onOpen()` is in general slow.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it is loaded with data, scripts and settings 

Comment: In this case you might consider to synchronize the range of interest (e.g.with `=IMPORTRANGE`) into a secondary spreadsheet and attach your script to the secondary spreadsheet which does not contain irrelevant heavy contents.

Comment: This is a great idea.